# document.getElementById.innerHTML works only once - how to configure global copy elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document

I want to create an external js-file, in which I can configure the copy of several elements in my html file. I'm using *document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "what ever";* to "inject" or "add" my copy to html elements that have a certain id.

This works out fine, however when I have more than one element with the same id in my html file, the html from my js-file is only added to the first element **but the html from my js-file should be added to all elements with the same id**

**That's my html construct:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="copy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<strong id="back-button"></strong>
</div>

....

<div>
<strong id="back-button"></strong>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**And that's my JS file:**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function addcopy() {

        /* global */
        document.getElementById("back-button").innerHTML = "go back";
});
});
```

Any help or tip is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use class, because `id`s can be used only once.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="copy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="back-button">
</div>
....
<div class="back-button">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function addcopy() {
         /* global */
         $(".back-button").html("<strong>go back</strong>");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for quick help - this way it's working perfect!

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. BTW, you should also vote up all the useful answers. All of them are correct too.

Answer (score 1):

In js you can do it like this:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0].innerHTML = "Good afternoon:)!";
```

Then you can loop through all elements of this class.

Answer (score 0):

`id` attribute should be unique, I know that in JQuery if you want to use multiple selector you can use `class` instead.

Or you can use `name` and the `getElementsByName()` function that will give you an array of elements in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have jQuery, why not use `$('#back-button').html('go back')` instead of the plain/native JS?

However, you have more than one button and **IDs *must* be unique**, so you cannot use an id for this. Use `class="back-button"` and the following jQuery code:

```
$('.back-button').html('go back');
```

Comment: Yes, [why](http://jsperf.com/jquery-id-vs-getelementbyid-id) [not](http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-jquery-html-insert/3) indeed.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for quick help - you are right - it is working perfectly that way!

Answer (score 0):

Please use class instead of id for the HTML elements and use jquery to fill in the required text.

```
<div>
<strong class="back-button"></strong>
</div>


$('.back-button').text('go back');   // OR
$('.back-button').html('go back');
```